# Appropriate Cache Friendly Associative Container For An Entity Component System

Tags: c++, component-based, data-structure, entity-component, data-oriented

The intro to this problem is a bit of a long one so my apologies in advance. In short I am asking for suggestion as to what type of collection I should use to store data for a particular part of my system.

I have an entity component system in place where a static EntityManager creates and stores components within vectors of their own type, and creates Entities storing them in either a vector for dynamic entities or a vector for static entities. Something like this:

```
#define COMPONENTS X(MeshComponent) X(CameraComponent) X(PointLightComponent) X(DirectionLightComponent)
#define X(ARG) std::vector<ARG>,
using ComponentTuple = std::tuple<COMPONENTS Empty>;
#undef X

class EntityManager {
    static ComponentTuple components;

    vector<Entity>& getDynamicEntities() {
        static vector<Entity> entities;
        return entities;
    }

    vector<Entity>& getStaticEntities() {
        static vector<Entity> entities;
        return entities;
    }
}
```

Without getting into too much detail each Entity has an id (stored as a `short` which determines its dynamic or static status and its index within the respective vector).

Each Component has its own id (an `unsigned short` referring to its index in its respective vector) and an Entity id, referring to the entity it is "attached" to.

At this point all the Entity object is, is an ID and useful functions. To make it more useful I decided to let the Entity object store a collection of id's (unsigned shorts) of its own components (to make searching for the entities specific components faster). My initial plan was to use an `unordered_map` data structure it like so:

```
class Entity {
    friend class EntityManager;
private:
    short id = SHRT_MAX;
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, vector<unsigned short>> components;
}
```

Thinking on it though, this introduces at least two (from what I can see) levels of indirection. One to the hash table produced by the unordered map and another to the vector storing the actual id's. With this in mind I was wondering if anyone else would be able to suggest a more cache friendly data structure. If not a simple reassurance that my choice was a correct one will also suffice (as right now I can't help but feel that there is a better way).

Some of the things that I would like the collection to do:

1) I would like to be able to search the collection by ComponentType (because components may share the same ID but be stored in different vectors)

2) I would like the collection to be expansive (not all entities will have the same components and it just seems wasteful to have an array for all potential Component Types when the entity may only have one)

3) I would like the potential to have multiple Components of the same Component Type in the collection (in the example given above maybe some Components have two `PointLightComponent`s)

Any suggestions or comments would be greatly appreciated as I've been wracking my brain on this one for some time now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've no idea how that `unordered_map` is implemented internally, yet you're wracking your brain? Get on with your game, and optimise much later on. It won't be the end of the world to replace the `unordered_map` if you have to. But until you see the game design underperforming in a real-world use-case, you won't know what to address. Address it _now_, and you almost certainly _won't_ be addressing that which you'll have ultimately _needed_ to address. Facepalm when you then realise the time you wasted on this. There's little point in optimisation that is uninformed. Use what works, for now.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer, that's fair and I know I probably shouldn't be spending all this time on it, but if ends up becoming a problem wouldn't refactoring later cause much more of a problem then just planning it out now and proceeding?

Comment: No, absolutely not. One thing you should know about refactoring is it's something we all have to do, we often dread it, but we shouldn't. Agile development philosophy states _refactor mercilessly_; I couldn't agree more, from experience. Expect to refactor in phases, every few days. It is a far safer approach than spending countless hours fussing over the fine details, never realising they will never even come to fruition as you usually end up choosing a different approach. Software dev works in phases like this: for now, use the simplest thing that works. It's how the big companies work, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Do the simplest thing that works](http://wiki.c2.com/?DoTheSimplestThingThatCouldPossiblyWork), *especially* early on.

If you've ever seen videos of triple-A titles in alpha, you'll know how slow / buggy they are. This is normal; in fact, it's *desirable*. And it's often because they used the *naive* solution to problems.

Agile development philosophy states [Refactor Mercilessly](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/refactor.html); I couldn't agree more, from experience. Expect to refactor in phases, every few days. It is a far safer approach than spending countless hours fussing over the fine details, never realising they will never even come to fruition as you usually end up choosing a different approach. Software dev works in phases like this: for now, use the simplest thing that works. It's how the big companies work, too.

The most important thing is to write code that does *something*, otherwise you don't even know what you ultimately have to optimise. Making progress means glossing over fine performance details.

What this means in your case is: don't expect a one-size-fits-all data structure. What I suggest is you start with the *essential needs* data structure (for which I think `unordered_map` will do fine), and either

1. use more optimal data structures "alongside" (can be fraught with peril, as you must keep various data structures in sync) or
2. sort / search that primary data structure in non-optimal ways, and maintain just that one. (This means for example doing `O(n)` searches over your `map`)

It is far more productive to code this way and aim for lower thresholds e.g. in unit count, number of AI updates per minute, and so on, than to try to aim high from the start. Then you have the basic principle and can focus later on the finer implementation details once the concept has crystallised.

If you're struggling with the idea of gutting your game, my view is you need to spend more time practicing refactoring, as it is an unavoidable necessity in our field. Write code to throw it away.

**Closing tip** When you find yourself wanting to access the same data structure in a variety of different ways (even worse, *potentially*), there is problem in your conceptualisation of the problem. I got this a lot as a younger programmer. That's the point at which, in order to get meaningful work done, you need to decide what is the primary thing you need, start coding that up in the simplest way possible, and go from there. You'll usually find along the way that you didn't need all the rest!

Comment: Supporting this point about simplicity, I just did a comparison between an associative structure versus just naive O(n) scanning a list of (type, id) pairs. For entities with just a handful of components, the two methods were in the same ballpark. So this might not be the performance bottleneck to worry about most right now. ;)

Answer (score 2):

ArcaneEngineer's advice is good, particularly for early development (to an extent - once you configure your engine to work a particular way, it can be significantly hard to rework it later).

For best performance, look into [slot maps](http://seanmiddleditch.com/data-structures-for-game-developers-the-slot-map/) (also known as slot arrays, packed arrays) and [colony](http://www.plflib.org/colony.htm).

A slot map has the advantage of already having the map (id) functionality built in, and the unordered iterative performance of an array.
A colony has the advantage of stable pointers to elements regardless of insertion/erasure, and a faster insertion/erasure mechanism than slot maps. It has slightly lower iteration speed.
I would not recommend unordered_map, as it has well-known and significant performance issues due to way it was conceived in the standard preventing better cache-friendly implementations.

A couple of slot_x implementations:

[SG14 slot_map](https://github.com/WG21-SG14/SG14/blob/master/SG14/slot_map.h)

[Masstronaut slot_array](https://gist.github.com/Masstronaut/e96b62bf2b3dffc61af6)